# Gradient text till first line CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make following

[image]

Linear gradient up until first line and move "this is another text" accordingly. Right now if I have less text (one line) and it works, but when screen size changes or more text is added it will not work.

Like below

[image]

any suggestions to make it responsive only one line is shown and rest is hidden so that "this is another text" can move up close.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ktxnt4t/

**HTML**

```
<div class="text">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mi urna. Phasellus porta volutpat ipsum, at dapibus ligula. 
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="text2">
     this is another text
</div>
```

**css**

```
.text {position: relative; color:red; text-align:center;}
.text2 {position: relative; color:red; text-align:center; top:10px;}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(243,243,243,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(243,243,243,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(243,243,243,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(243,243,243,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(243,243,243,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(243,243,243,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f3f3f3', GradientType=0 );

    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The only way to do that with just css is stop word wrapping - which will break your page on small devices

Comment: do you mean: https://jsfiddle.net/1ktxnt4t/1/ ?

Comment: That could work...

Comment: problem is that in this case you are hidding content. you should add : `pointer-events:none;` to `.overlay` so text can be selected or links/forms can be clicked if any there ...

Comment: yes, thanks! please put it as answer.